# PHP: Cannot print out mysqli error on prepare statement

Tags: php, mysqli

I had the following error `Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object` and realised from research that I needed to add error checking on my prepare statement, as it is probably returning false.

I therefore had this ->

```
 if ($statement = $this ->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO users(name, email, gender, usrDOB, encrypted_password, salt, created_at) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,NOW())")) {
        $statement->bind_param("ssssss", $name, $email, $gender, $usrDOB, $encryptedPassword, $salt);
        $result = $statement->execute();
        $statement->close();

        if ($result) {
            $statement = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email =?");
            $statement->bind_param("s", $email);
            $statement->execute();
            $user = $statement->get_result()->fetch_assoc();
            $statement->close();
            return $user;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }else{
        printf($this->conn->error());
    }
```

however there seems to be an error when printing out the error() as it says it isn't defined.

I tried conn without the $this, but to no avail.

ANy ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by [this url](http://www.codingforums.com/php/340824-call-member-function-bind_param.html) using the error checking near the bottom of the thread of answers.

```
$query = "INSERT INTO users (Fuid, Ffname)   
VALUES (?, ?)   
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE users   
 SET Ffname = ?"; 

if(!$stmt = $db->prepare($query)){ 
    // prepare failed 
    printf("Prepare failed: %s<br>Error: %s.<br>", $query, $db->error); 
} else { 
    // prepare worked 
    $stmt->bind_param('iss',$fuid,$ffname,$ffname); 
    if(!$stmt->execute()){ 
        // execute failed 
        printf("Execute failed: %s<br>Error: %s.<br>", $query, $stmt->error); 
    } else { 
        // execute worked 

        // any code dependent on the insert query running would go here... 

    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can print the error if the statement fails like this:

```
$statement->execute();
if ($statement->error) {
    var_dump($statement->error);
}
```

Comment: I removed my previous if statement for the prepared statement error checking, and added these lines below the execute() and the same error shows `Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object` @AndreasLinden